# Facing issue with camera application

Tags: android, camera, android-sdcard

I am working on a camera application where I have to click the image
 and save it in a newly created folder for images in SD card

this is my `MainActivity.java` file.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        Button cambutton;
        ImageView photoImage=null;

        private static final String TAG = "CallCamera";
        private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ = 0;

        Uri fileUri=null;
        //ImageView photoImage1 = null;

        private File getOutputPhotoFile() {

              File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getPackageName());

              if (!directory.exists()) {
                if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
                  Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
                  return null;
                }
              }

              String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());

              return new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"  
                                + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button camButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncam);
            ImageView photoImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);

            camButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent i = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(getOutputPhotoFile());
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);

                    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ);

                }
            });

        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
              if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQ) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                  Uri photoUri = null;
                  if (data == null) {
                    // A known bug here! The image should have saved in fileUri
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully", 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    photoUri = fileUri;
                  } else {
                    photoUri = data.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved successfully in: " + data.getData(), 
                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                  showPhoto(photoUri.getPath());


                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Callout for image capture failed!", 
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              }
        }

        private void showPhoto(String photoUri) {
              File imageFile = new File (photoUri);
              if (imageFile.exists()){
                 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
                 BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), bitmap);
                 photoImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                 photoImage.setImageDrawable(drawable);
              }       
        }

    }
```

when I am running this , it runs really well but when I try to save the image, application crashes.

my `logcat` is given below..

```
 07-08 03:51:02.976: W/dalvikvm(2104): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1d4bb20)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Process: com.dev.camera, PID: 2104
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.dev.camera/com.dev.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.dev.camera.MainActivity.showPhoto(MainActivity.java:126)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at com.dev.camera.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:95)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):     ... 11 more
07-08 03:51:08.536: I/Process(2104): Sending signal. PID: 2104 SIG: 9
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who\_null,request=1,result=-1, data =Intent{( has extras )}} to activity;NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827237/failure-delivering-result-resultinfowho-null-request-1-result-1-data-intent)

Comment: @Sreekanth Here in StackOverFlow, I have seen more than 10 question asking for the same error, but the reason behind every question was different. So dont tell me any may be may be not type links. and I would like to ask for read my question first then check my logcat. thanx

Comment: if you really need help, point out what issue you are facing and find out where you are facing it,this is not a good practice , when a issue happen all are simply posting full code and full code, even they dot try to find where it happen

Comment: @Sreekanth it is very easy to mark down a question... and this is very good this becoz when you dont have the answer.. just simply mark negetive the question. Sir, if you have read my code, You can find that I have mentioned where I am getting error.

Comment: that is not the place where you are getting error, please do debug the app and find out the error

Comment: write a log and find out what is the value in ur `photoUri`, i think it is null, so the error happening

Answer (score 0):

1)in click event:
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

2)in onActivityResult:

```
if ((requestCode == 1)) {

                // -----------path getting from intent------------
                String photoPath = null;
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] { Media.DATA,         Media.DATE_ADDED,MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION },
                        Media.DATE_ADDED, null, "date_added ASC");
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor    .getColumnIndex(Media.DATA)));
                        photoPath = uri.toString();

                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    cursor.close();
                }
 }
```

3)in your manifest:

Comment: now I am getting this error... 07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): Process: com.dev.camera, PID: 2104
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.dev.camera/com.dev.camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 03:51:02.986: E/AndroidRuntime(2104):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)